# DB Transaction schedules

Tags: database, transactions

I basically understand what Serial and Seralizable Schedules are but the question I want to answer is

> Briefly explain the terms, Serializable Schedule, Serial Schedule and
>   Equivalent Schedule

What is the *difference between a Serealizable Schedule and an Equivalent Schedule?*

Anything to do with the order of Transactions? or the values writing in to them?

Answer (score 1):

**Serial Schedule**

- One process at a time
- Does not interleave

**Equivalent Schedule**

- When the effect of executing different schedules are the same

**Serializable Schedule**

- A schedule that is equivalent to some Serial Values